# how to use regular expression to save a part of email

Tags: php, regex

I have email reports coming in in the following format(there is usually different amount of spaces between Label(vehicle, address..) and colons):

```
- Vehicle               :Jeep Liberty
- Trigger             :161 Paris Cresent
- Address              :167 Paris Cres
```

I am trying to save to a database address information. I tried this (it gets only one word though):

```
$message='- Address             :167 Paris Cres';
if (preg_match('/(?<=Address             :)\S+/i', $message, $match)){
    echo $match[0] . "<br>";
}else{echo "fail <br>";}
```

Please help me to make it work.

Comment: If you want us to "help you make it work" you're going to have to define how it "didn't work", what it is supposed to do, and what debugging you have performed. This isn't a giant crowdsourced software development team.

Comment: Did you even check if it is displaying correctly?

Comment: I know a lot of times this isn't an option, but I would suggest your first action should be to try and get the format of the emails changed to something more easily parse-able. There's a reason why things like xml and json exist.

Comment: @Crayon Violent Unfortunately changing format of the emails is not an option. They are generated by third party.

Comment: I don't understand why you are giving this user a hard time. The regular expression is obviously incorrect. You don't need to run the code or ask for more information to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to just use a grouped match than to use a lookbehind.

```
$message='- Address             :167 Paris Cres';

if (preg_match('/\bAddress\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*$/mi', $message, $match)){
    echo $match[1] . "<br>";
}else{
    echo "fail <br>";
}
```